# sql syntax is missing & error handling

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to handle errors in sql script, I have put some statements for it.But its not working. I think i am missing begin & end statements position.
here is my sql script please correct it.

```
set colsep ',';
set trimout off;
set pagesize 0;
set trimspool off;
set feedback off;
set heading off;
set heading off;
set verify off;
set errorlogging on;
var envame varchar2(20)
exec :envame := '&1'
set errorlogging on;
spool C:\UsersDesktop\batch\pres64.csv app
begin
select '&&1', user_name, user_id from employee where designation = 'manager';

exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');
end;

exit;
```

this gives output as
12
13
14
15
.
.
please suggest modifications..

Comment: `spool` is a SQL*Plus command, it cannot run within a `begin..end` PL/SQL block.

Comment: Also, `select` without an `INTO` is not valid PL/SQL.

Comment: Finally, `when others then` without a `raise` is virtually always very bad practice.

Comment: I have modified question, please suggest changes

Comment: good start but you haven't resolved the missing `INTO` yet.

Comment: SPOOL won't work in PL/SQL. And as Jeffrey already said, `WHEN OTHERS` without `RAISE` is a bad practice. Avoid `when others`. Read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> spool C:\UsersDesktop\batch\pres64.csv app
>
> begin
>
> select '&&1', user_name, user_id from employee where designation = 'manager';
>
> exception when others then
>
> dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');

You have mixed `SQL*Plus` with `PL/SQL` exception handling. `SPOOL` is a SQL*Plus command. It won't work if you use the `BEGIN-END` PL/SQL block.

Since you are using `SQL*Plus`, I would strongly recommend to use the new **SQL*Plus error logging feature** rather doing it in **PL/SQL**. It was introduced in **release 11.1**.

I have written an article about it here http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/sqlplus-error-logging-new-feature-release-11-1/

For example,

```
SQL> set errorlogging on
SQL> show errorlogging
errorlogging is ON TABLE LALIT.SPERRORLOG
SQL> desc sperrorlog
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------------
 USERNAME                                           VARCHAR2(256)
 TIMESTAMP                                          TIMESTAMP(6)
 SCRIPT                                             CLOB
 IDENTIFIER                                         VARCHAR2(256)
 MESSAGE                                            CLOB
 STATEMENT                                          CLOB

SQL> selct * from dual;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "selct * fr..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL>
```

So, the above **SP2 error** is now **logged** in the **sperrorlog** table.

```
SQL> select timestamp, username, statement, message from sperrorlog;

TIMESTAMP                      USERNAME STATEMENT            MESSAGE
------------------------------ -------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------
06-APR-15 10.42.49.000000 AM   LALIT    selct * from dual;   SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "selct * fr...
                                                             " - rest of line ignored.


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit.. but please check sql syntax in my script is it ok?

Comment: While the new logging feature is interesting, this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Also, there is nothing wrong with omitting the `DECLARE` from a PL/SQL block - it's legal to start with a `begin`.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp OP is using SQL*Plus and mixing PL/SQL exception handling. So I think this is just like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, there is nothing wrong in ommitting the `DECLARE` part. I just showed an example syntax for a PL/SQL block. Declare is optional, required only to declare the variables. else `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` is just fine. But, the question is not about this in particular but error logging. So, I did not get deeper into the syntax part.

Comment: Lalit, I was referring to this: "You have written the exception block without any PL/SQL scope." which is not what the problem is. As you say, they have mixed SQL*Plus and PL/SQL code, which is the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Aah, I see. Sounds ambiguous. Will edit the statement. Thanks Jeffrey